# Nurse Chapel's tattoos

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-strange-new-worlds

In the newest Star Trek series, I noticed that Nurse Chapel has tattoos on her hands. This is of course explained by the actor Jess Bush having them herself (as seen in the second screenshot).

Has there been an in-universe explanation (maybe in books or comics), i.e. some ritual on an expedition, for Nurse Chapel having these tattoos?

[image: Screen capture of Nurse Chapel in S01E07 with her hands raised showing her tattoos]
<sub>[Source: [Chapel In Action | Star Trek Strange New Worlds S01E07](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pakEu_9OYtc)]</sub>

[image: Screen capture of actor Jess Bush during an interview showing the tattoos on her hands]
<sub>[Source: [The Ready Room-Checking In With Jess Bush (Paramount+)](https://youtu.be/HwvBWcMVBdI)]</sub>

Comment: What sort of explanation are you looking for? Tattoos are not unknown in Trek, and presumably fashions come and go like in the real world. Are you trying to ask why the character of Chapel doesn't have them in TOS?

Comment: I realize that Chapel from TOS wouldn't have them since that show came before (though it would be interesting if there was an explanation for **that**). I am just wondering if there was an explanation outside of the show, maybe books or comics.

Comment: @agraza ah okay, well I don't think there has been. Tattoos are rare in Trek, and usually religious in nature.

Comment: Downvoted from 3 back to 0 with no explanation.

Comment: The newer shows (Discovery, quite notably) don't seem to be all that beholden to original-series and TNG vintage canon - the writers and art directors seem to cherry-pick elements and references as it suits them, sidestepping or ignoring canon where it gets in the way of their creative interests. No surprise that between casting, make-up, and CGI post, something like a performer's personal tattoos would be let through without any attempt at in-universe explanation.

Comment: FWIW in TOS "The Way to Eden", several of the "space hippies" can be seen sporting body paint (which might be intended for the audience to interpret as futuristic tattoos).

Comment: ["Star Trek: Strange New Worlds Killed Canon (And That's Okay)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-GFh-tmCpA)

Comment: @AnthonyX I realized that over the course of **decades** things will change. So I am not really concerned with if canon is broken/disregarded. I'm just wondering if there has been an explanation recently; even if it was referenced in a Twitter/X posting or interview.

Comment: Is there any canon that says people don't have tattoos in the future, or in Starfleet? All sorts of religious and cultural garb seems okay, e.g. Worf's Klingon sash thing. Boimler dyes his hair blue. As far as I know nothing has ever been said in canon about purely decorative tattoos.

Comment: @agarza What did you mean by "I realize that Chapel from TOS wouldn't have them since that show came before?" I think you mean that SNW is set before TOS, but I just want things to be totally clear.

Comment: I don't understand what's so confusing about this question, or why it was downvoted four times. It seems pretty clear to me that the OP is asking how or why Nurse Chapel got the tattoos, not whether or not they exist in _Star Trek._

Comment: @SovereignInquiry I meant that Barrett's Chapel from TOS was before Bush's Chapel from SNW in television production.

Comment: @agarza I see. Thanks for the clarification.